# Python's ThreadPoolExecutor.submit() working differently in windows and linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, apache-kafka, submit, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to receive kafka messages using the following script.The messages are received in windows but are not received in linux system. Also when the run function is called in the below code, the python console in windows keeps printing "Inside the threadpool" continuosly but the python console in linux prints "Inside the threadpool" only once and then the code hangs(or atleast doesn't give anything in the console)

```
def run(self):
    print('Running KafkaThread. . . ')
    try:
        while True:
            print("Inside the threadpool")
            for consumer, callback in consumers:
                thread_pool.submit(Handler.consumer_request, consumer, callback)
            time.sleep(5)
    except Exception:
        logger.error(f'Error occurred in {__name__} : {sys.exc_info()[0]}', exc_info=True)
        raise


def consumer_request(consumer, callback):
    key, value = None, None
    try:
        for msg in consumer:
            key = msg.key if msg.key is None else msg.key.decode('utf-8')
            value = msg.value
            callback.on_success(key, value)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'ERROR occurred while consuming from kafka {sys.exc_info()[0]}', exc_info=True)
        callback.on_error(key, e)
```

Comment: Is your Kafka broker is accessible from both Windows and Linux ? This might comes from the fact that Linux machine does not  reach broker Kafka correctly and then hang

Comment: Yes. I have even verified. I used the following command to receive the messages sent by the producer in linux. Messages are received instantaneosly.'/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic doc_analysis --from-beginning'